# Schema Validation for xs:date | Date Patterns

Tags: regex, date, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am trying to create a schema which contains a date field. This date field is of the format DD-MM-YYYY.
BizTalk by default accepts date in format YYYY-MM-DD.

I tried using Regular expression and below is the xsd snippet of the concerned field

```
<xs:element name="FieldName">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0,1]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4}" /> 
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I then tried to validate a file using this but it errors out with tha pattern constraint failed.

What is wrong with the regex expression?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is the regular expression?

Comment: the regular expression is "[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0,1]{1}[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{4}"

Comment: What app/business problem are you trying to solve?  BizTalk itself doesn't actually care about date formats.

Answer (score 0):

I would hardly recommend to not use this regex, because it allows unvalid dates such as 39-19-9999.

If you want to allow such unvalid date it's up to you but if not, I found this regex here:

`^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$`

wich also allow some invalid dates such as 31-06-2014 (there is no 31. day in month june) but there are less unvalid dates allowed within this regex.

Comment: @brothers28- right now the problem is that the existing regex won't accept actual dates too. for ex. "20-06-2014"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that your field is of type `xs:date`. The fact that BizTalk accepts the format YYYY-MM-DD, that is not a BizTalk thing, that comes from XSD specification itself. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp

You'll notice that your regular expression is added to the schema as a `xs:restriction`. This is used to further restrict the data contained in that node, but it must still be a valid `xs:date`. Therefore, I believe that the only way to deal with this is to change the type of your field to `xs:string` and deal with the date some other way (perhaps convert it in a map).